# Printing a `vector<pair<int, int>>`

Tags: c++, vector

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, int>> v;
    v.push_back({ 1, 5 });
    v.push_back({ 2,3 });
    v.push_back({ 1,2 });
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
}
```

I'm getting an error `C2679` `binary "=": no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type "std::pair<int, int>" (or there is no acceptable conversion)`. I have no idea what this means, or why `copy` doesn't print. Without `copy`, there is no error, but I want to print out `vector v`. Is there some other way to do htis?

Comment: `std::cout` doesn't know how to print a `std::pair<int, int>`. You either have to teach it by providing a custom operator of your own or print just the elements of the pairs.

Answer (score 2):

After you sort you can use a for-each loop to iterate over the vector container and print the pairs:

```
for(const pair<int,int>& x: v)
{
  cout << x.first << " " << x.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: It is called a **ranged** for loop, not a for-each loop. Although, it means the same thing.

Comment: Why is `const` used here in the for loop?

Comment: It is a good practice if you are not going to be modifying the elements that are inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're trying to print `std::pair<int, int>` using a function printing one `int`, that's not going to work.

Since `std::ostream` doesn't have an overload taking `std::pair` by default, you have to provide an overload for the `operator<<` taking the type `std::pair<int, int>` yourself:

```
// This is necessary because ADL doesn't work here since
// the std::ostream_iterator will be looking for the overload
// in the std namespace.
struct IntPair : std::pair<int, int> {
    using std::pair<int, int>::pair;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const IntPair& p) {
    o << p.first << " " << p.second;
    return o;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<IntPair> v;
    v.push_back({ 1, 5 });
    v.push_back({ 2, 3 });
    v.push_back({ 1, 2 });
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<IntPair>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to cout a `std::pair` because there is no stream insertion (`<<`) operator overload for it. You could instead use `std::for_each`:

```
std::for_each(
    v.begin(),
    v.end(),
    [](const auto& p) { std::cout << p.first << "," << p.second << std::endl; });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is the fastest way what I know

```
template<typename T, typename Y>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::pair<T,Y>>& pair) -> std::ostream&
{
    for(const auto& el : pair)
        os << el.first << ' ' << el.second << '\n';
    return os;
}
```